# Android: Trigger an event when the user exits a geofence

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

Is there a way to define a geofence (center and radius) around the device's current location, and have the system trigger a callback function in my app when the device exits the geofence?

I would like to avoid extensive GPS usage, so I would prefer a system message over periodic GPS polling, even at the price of reduced accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Geofence` API in `Google Play Services`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) you can find the documentation to use it. You can have up to 100 geofences at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the GeoFencing API never intelligently retrieves locations from the GPS hardware. The GeoFence API will observe the most accurate location available from the OS or if no location is currently available, it will cause a location to be calculated from Wifi / Cellular. (which sucks because cellular is wildly inaccurate and wifi is often unavailable)

So to get at all responsive or accurate results out of the Geofencing API you have to set up your Geofences and then poll the GPS hardware on an interval, not even doing anything with the result received, so that under the surface you are providing worthwhile data to the OS.

I can't speak specifically to the behaviour of LocationManager.addProximityAlert but I doubt it behaves any differently.

Answer (score 1):

`LocationManager.addProximityAlert`.  It uses both GPS and network internally, presumably only turning on GPS when close.   Does exactly what you want.